# How to get the start parameter when app starts from custom url scheme for Android in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I'm able to start the application, using the custom URL Scheme

```
<a href="myapp://customurl/?user_token=12345">Start My App</a>
```

The application lunches as usual, but i did need the key `user_token=12345`. I had less experience with this framework, so don't get any work around. Need help.

Secondly, Can i pass multiple keys using the Custom Schema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [Android WebIntent Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent) for this.

You can send multiple key

```
<a href="myapp://customurl/?user_token=12345&user_id=12">Start My App</a>
```

Use this as like

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", GetCustomUrl, false);
```

Then the function would be

```
function GetCustomUrl() {
    window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
        if(url !== "") {
            // Here you need to first split with "?" then later with "&"
            var link = url.split("?"); 
            var keysPair = link[1].split("&");
            // use as per your need
        }
    });
}
```

You can check the plugin site for more details.

Comment: The plugin link above is dead. You might mean https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent

Comment: Yes that right. The above one is for PhoneGap 2.6.0 or before. So there might be some new enhancement for newer version. :)